# 'in sense' v.s. 'point of view'

Tags: word-choice

I just don't know what's the difference.

- When we use *in what sense*, we mean *in different sense, we can conclude different results*.
- When we use *point of view*, we also mean *in different point of views, we can conclude different results*.

So, when we want to say *some questions are open, and from different view/sense leads different results* then which to choose?

Those two phases are translated to (into?) two similar phrases in my native language (Mandarin).

Comment: I didn't get your question. What is your mother tongue?

Comment: Hi, Manoochehr, I have updated my question. hope it is easier to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of “in a sense” and “with a certain point of view” overlap but are not identical. ***“point of view”*** implies a more personal take on things, while ***in a sense*** tends to be used for well-established interpretations (like, scientific theories, or the like).

Comment: Good Explanation

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports the following meaning for *point of view*, and *in a sense*:

> point of view /pɔɪnt əv/ /ə vju/
>   noun
>   a particular attitude or way of considering a matter: *I'm trying to get Matthew to change his point of view*.
>   • (in fictional writing) the narrator's position in relation to the story being told: *this story is told from a child's point of view*.
>   • the position from which something or someone is observed: *certain aspects are not visible from a single point of view*.

> in a (or one) sense
>   used to indicate a particular interpretation of a statement or situation: *in a sense, behavior cannot develop independently of the environment*.